# Transparencia de un div, sin que sus elementos del interior sean transparentes

Tags: css, css3

Buenas!

¿Como haceis para tener un div con cierta transparencia, pero que su contenido no lo tenga?

Es decir, estaba probando a hacer una página donde todo su fondo es una imagen, y entonces quería ponerle un menú de navegación en su parte superior. Y este lo quiero oscurecer, pero que se siga viendo el fondo.

Hasta aquí, mi corta experiencia me ha dicho que le aplicase una *opacity*, el problema es que ahora su contenido también está con esa *opacity* y eso no me interesa.

¿Como haceis para que solo sea el *div* contenedor el que tenga esa opacidad?

Adjunto una imagen donde se ve, que el nombre tiene una transparencia que yo no quiero, este debería verse perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Muestra lo que haz intentado hasta ahora...

Comment: En vez de usar la opacidad que afectará también a los hijos de esa división, usa **background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)** (por ejemplo) de ese modo tan solo estás cambiando el estilo del fondo de ese elemento pero NO de los elementos que este contenga.

Comment: Disculpa aldanux soy novato por aquí, la próxima vez adjunto código. Es que pensé que sería algo muy sencillo para vosotros y no haría falta.

Comment: Gracias Javi, esa ha sido la solución!!! :) ¿Como cierro ahora el post?

Answer (score 2):

Tiene que utilizar colores con el valor alpha, osea, rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). `Opacity` modifica todo el contenido mientras que el color rgba no:

```css
div{
 background:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.45); 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1> 
    <p>Esto es un texto</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Quien dio el voto negativo. Gracias. No me había fijado que deje opacity por error en la regla css. Ya arregle la respuesta.

Comment: Yo no fui, pero de todos modos te he dejado voto positivo. :)